# Why I am not able view PDF through document viewer

Tags: pdf

I am not able to look my PDF. There comes a dialog box when I try to open it . It's like this:

```
Unable to open document “file:///home/ankur/Desktop/10th/__MACOSX/10th/._BIOLOGY_LIFE PROCESSES(10th)_L1.pdf”.

File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported
```

Comment: please [edit] your post and add the output of `file '/home/ankur/Desktop/10th/__MACOSX/10th/._BIOLOGY_LIFE PROCESSES(10th)_L1.pdf'`

Comment: Does tis happen with only this PDF? Points to a broken PDF file, then.